# Using Volusion API to Import Order Data

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, volusion

I've been trying to use the Volusion API to import order data with no luck and support through Volusion is limited.  I tend to lean towards a PHP solution, and their web site has this example for using the API for Import with php...

```
<?php
    //  Create the Xml to POST to the Webservice
    $Xml_to_Send = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>";
    $Xml_to_Send .= "<Volusion_API>";
    $Xml_to_Send .= "<!--";
    $Xml_to_Send .= "    xml input file for \"\"";
    $Xml_to_Send .= "-->";
    $Xml_to_Send .= "</Volusion_API>";

    //  Create the Header
    $url = "https://www.xxxxxcomusa.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=xxxxx@xxxxcomusa.com &EncryptedPassword=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&Import=Insert";
    $header  = "POST".$url." HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
    $header .= "Request-number: 1 \r\n";
    $header .= "Document-type: Request \r\n";
    $header .= "Interface-Version: Test 1.4 \r\n";
    $header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $Xml_to_Send;

    //  Post and Return Xml
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    //  Check for Errors
    if (curl_errno($ch)){
        print curl_error($ch);
    } else {
       curl_close($ch);
    }

    //  Display the Xml Returned on the Browser
    echo $data;
?>
```

I've edited this accordingly in order to get an order updated (used "Import=Update")  but there is no 'data' output on the resulting page and the record does not get updated.  I am able to get data returned from the api using a similar url so I know my encrypted password is correct.  I think I also determined that the line that reads...

```
$header  = "POST".$url." HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
```

should read ...

```
   $header  = "POST ".$url." HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
```

with a space after POST but I'm still not able to successfully update a record.  I was hoping someone might have had success and can share more specifics on how you were able to import an update using the Volusion API (and hopefully PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying with `CUSTOMREQUEST` you can use below one. It sends your headers appropriately.

First make the header as below:

```
$header  = array(
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-transfer-encoding: text",
    "Request-number: 1",
    "Document-type: Request",
    "Interface-Version: Test 1.4"
);
```

After that make your post request as below with the above header.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Xml_to_Send); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

Comment: Thank you Sabuj.  Your suggestion got me far enough along so that I believe my request was eventually formatted and sent correctly only to be replied with "Only Insert Mode is supported for Orders". For the benefit of others trying to accomplish a similar task this is what I ended up with for code...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I ended up with but as I mention above it appears that Import=Update does not work with Volusion Order data, but similar code should work when trying to use the Volusion API and PHP to import.  Thanks again for your help Sabuj!

```
<?php

    $file = file_get_contents('mydir/singleorder.txt', true);

//  Create the Xml to POST to the Webservice

    $Xml_to_Send = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>";
    $Xml_to_Send .= "<Volusion_API>";
//  $Xml_to_Send .= "<!--";
    $Xml_to_Send .= $file;
//  $Xml_to_Send .= "\"\"";
//  $Xml_to_Send .= "-->";
    $Xml_to_Send .= "</Volusion_API>";

    $url = "https://www.xxxxxusa.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=xxxx@xxxxxxxcom.com&EncryptedPassword=0000000000000000000000000000xxxxxxxxxx&Import=Update";

//  Create the Header   

    $header  = array(
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-transfer-encoding: text",
    "Request-number: 1",
    "Document-type: Request",
    "Interface-Version: Test 1.4"
);

    //  Post and Return Xml
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Xml_to_Send); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    //  Check for Errors
    if (curl_errno($ch)){
        print curl_error($ch);
    } else {
       curl_close($ch);
    }

   //  Display the Xml Returned on the Browser
    echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should echo your file.

Because I was having the same issue, the remaining code is correct but may be your file path is wrong and doesn't get by PHP so thats why the records is not inserted.

When I changed the directory path is like this..

```
$file = file_get_contents('singleorder.txt', true);
```

It will be always in the same directory.
It started work fine. So try this for solution.